# PHPStorm - show all errors on inspection

Tags: phpstorm

PHPStorm newbie question.

I'd installed PHPStorm yesterday and was very impressed. It identified countless small issues with my code, like referencing non-static classes statically - I loved that it highlighted the problems in my open PHP files. There was a bit long list in the "inspection results" section (I think) which identified errors in various groupings. Great!

Today I can't get it to identify any errors at all, other than "Typos". Same project.

Clearly I messed up a a configuration somewhere, but I'm pretty baffled as to where. I've been through the Preferences section for the last hour trying different things, but can't get it to work as before.

Any tips...?

- Ben

Comment: Does your inspection profile still have all the needed inspections enabled? Check if `Code` | `Inspect Code` with the same profile produces the results that you need. Also note that `File` | `Power Save Mode` will turn off most of the inspections and errors highlighting when enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yup, the inspection profile looks good. I tried both the original + my own. Power Save Mode is off, too.

Comment: Try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and restart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Editor not doing proper code highlighting or not working inspections can be caused by the corrupted caches.

The solution is to do `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and restart the IDE.

Comment: this didnt help in my case. @CrazyCoder

Comment: Disabling power save mode fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating caches didn't worked for me.

In my case inspections were disabled because I had activated a wrong profile that wasn't checking PHP issues.

So be sure to check the used profile:

[image: Right click on inspection indicator]

[image: Click on configure inspections]

[image: Select proper profile]