# Show warnings and errors on PhpStorm project tree?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

How to show if a file has warnings or errors on PhpStorm project tree?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPStorm - show all errors on inspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409850/phpstorm-show-all-errors-on-inspection)

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm have feature of showing errors in file/tree/code..
It will make it red line for error, yellow for warnings. and you can switch to that error/warning directly by clicking on that red/yellow line with Ctrl (Ctrl+click)